# Question on weak convergence

Tags: probability-theory

Let ${F_n}$ be a sequence of distribution functions such that ${F_n}$ converges to $F$ weakly and suppose each $F_n$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ , then is it true that $F$ is continuous?

Weak convergence means that if $a$ is a point of continuity of $F$ then $F_n(a)$ will converge to $F(a)$.  What I think is that even though $F_n$ are continuous it doesn't feel like $F$ should also be continuous.,but I can't find any example.

Comment: Yes if, in addition, the convergence is [uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems $F$ can be not continuous even though $F_n$ are continuous.
Let $F_n(x)$ be $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ maps which satisfy $F_n(x)=\left\{\begin{align}0 &&,x<0\\nx &&,0\leq x<\frac {1}{n}\\1&&,\frac 1n\leq x\end{align}\right.$

Then

$F(x)=\left\{\begin{align}0 &&,x\leq 0\\1&&,x>0 \end{align}\right.$
which is a counterexample.

Comment: This is good, but being a functional analysis answer, I would suggest being rigorous about domains and codomains.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thank you for your comment and I have edited my answer XD

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest way to look at this question  is to define $F_n$ as the distribution of $\frac  X  n$ where $X$ has  continuous distribution , say $N(0,1)$. Then $F_n$ converges to the distribtuion of the degenerate random variable $X=0$.